# TypeScript 3.7.2 - Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, optional-chaining

In my project I am using TS 3.7.2 which should support optional chaining. But when I try to use it like that: `const state = urlParams.state?.toString()` I get the error:

> Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled
>
> Add @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining (https://git.io/vb4Sk) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

I checked release notes and didn't see any requirements about adding tsconfig options for that feature.

I am wondering if I need babel plugin & config when I am using TS already, and how should I fix the error?

Comment: sounds like you are using create-react-app. Last time I checked this doesn't support optionalChaining in the babel config it uses. See this issue for updates: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7940

Comment: @BenClayton thanks! Hope they will release that update asap.
Could you post your comment as an answer, so I could mark it as solved?

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This sounds like you are using an older version of create-react-app.

Versions earlier than v3.3 don't support optionalChaining in the babel config it uses.

Support was added in CRA v3.3. See other answers for how to upgrade.

Answer (score 16):

Solved with a [release of the CRA v3.3.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.3.0). If someone still has same error as in the title make sure you've upgraded `react-scripts` package.

Comment: Updating is pretty quick and easy too: `yarn add --exact react-scripts@3.3.0`